# I want to pass a string array to main but keep spaces

Tags: c#, string, arguments, spaces

I want to pass a string to main, but I am having trouble with spaces.

I pass the string `"C:\Documents and Settings\desktop\..."` to the `Main(string[] args)` and I had:

```
args[0] = "C:\Documents" 
args[1] = "and"
args[2] = "Settings\desktop\..."
```

But what I want is:

```
args[0] = "C:\Documents and Settings\desktop\..."
```

Any way to keep spaces but concatenate to one element of the string? The code should also work with any number of spaces in a given file path, not just 2 in this case.

Comment: When you call a console program with an argument like `C:\documents and settings\desktop...`, you should surround the argument with quotation marks.  This will cause the entire string to show up in `args[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically handled by passing the arguments in quotes.

For example, if you call this as:

```
yourApp.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\desktop..."
```

You'll get the string in the first arg (`args[0]`).

For example, using this program:

```
using System;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var arg in args) Console.WriteLine(arg);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you run this with the command line argument as:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\desktop..."
```

(With the quotation marks in place), this will print:

> C:\Documents and Settings\desktop...

If that isn't an option, and you only have a single argument, you could always join the results:

```
using System;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string argument = String.Join(" ", args);

        Console.WriteLine(argument);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This will work without wrapping the path in quotes, but it assumes the entire path is a single path, only has one space in between "words", and has no other arguments in place.  Personally, I would recommend wrapping the call in quotation marks, as it's a standard convention.

Comment: Found out it was a combination of issues. Needed the quotes in the right place (accidentally put them in the wrong argument) and another part of my code had a bad value. It's fixed now thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just quote the string when you call your program from the command line?

EXAMPLE: `myprog "This is one argument"`

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        /*
         * EXAMPLE: test arg1 "arg2 with spaces" arg3
         * args[0]=arg1...
         * args[1]=arg2 with spaces...
         * args[2]=arg3...
         */
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                System.Console.WriteLine("args[{0}]={1}...", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```